# .htaccess to find the current page and change it to /game/PAGE

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I've tried looking for this answer but I can't find it anywhere.
I'm trying to make it so, for example: usersonline.php redirects to /game/usersonline

So far, I have this code in the .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^profile/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) viewprofile.php?viewuser=$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^/game/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

(Bearing in mind I'm really nooby at .htaccess) any help would be highly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you have an invalid line on your .htaccess.

Change:

```
RewriteRule ^/game/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

to:

```
RewriteRule   ^game/([^/]+)/$    /$1.php    [L]
```

This should do it. I hope it helps!

Comment: Hello, thankyou for your reply. It just now says file not found for some unknown reason

Answer (score 0):

I have tried many ways, in most cases, my directory shows up on the URL of the website when I wanted to enter.

**I solved as follows:**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

This code changes your websites beginning and put back your `REQUEST_URI` to its position.